# NodeJS: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'toString')

Tags: javascript, node.js

I have the following Javscript code:

```
const authenticationTypeMapping = (payload) => {
  const { API_CONFIG } = process.env;

  try {
    const apiConfig = JSON.parse(API_CONFIG.toString('utf8'));
    // set authenticationType to Federated for production
    if (apiConfig.API_BASE_URL.includes('prd')) {
      payload.authenticationTypeName = 'Federated';
      // set authenticationType to Federated for dev or UAT
    } else if (apiConfig.API_BASE_URL.includes('dev') || apiConfig.API_BASE_URL.includes('uat')) {
      payload.authenticationTypeName = 'Basic';
    }
  } catch (err) {
    console.log(`Failed to map authenticationType. Unable to parse Secret: ${err}`);
  }
  return payload;
};
```

But every time when call this method it return the following error: Failed to map authenticationType: TypeError: **Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'toString')**
It is obviously related to this line in the code:

```
const apiConfig = JSON.parse(API_CONFIG.toString('utf8'));
```

How can fix that error?

Comment: Confirm "APP_CONFIG" has value

Comment: "How can fix that error?" — It largely depends on what you want to do if it isn't defined.

Comment: To resolve this error, you should check the code to ensure that the object is defined before you access its properties or methods. You can do this using a conditional statement like "if (object != undefined)".